# What is yum equivalent of 'apt-get update'?

Tags: package-management, yum, apt

Debian's `apt-get update` fetches and updates the package index. Because I'm used to this way of doing things, I was surprised  to find that `yum update` does all that **and** upgrades the system. This made me curious of how to update the package index without installing anything.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

While `yum check-update` will check updates for installed packages, if it needs to be refreshed, so will most other commands.

The command that's strictly the equivalent of `apt-get update` is `yum makecache` ... however it's generally not recommended to run that directly, in yum.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence. Can you rephrase maybe?

Comment: It means that other `yum` commands, e.g. `yum upgrade` will automatically run `yum check-update` if necessary.  In other words, `yum upgrade` is basically the same as `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Thank you! yum check-update did not helps me against 404 errors. But yum makecache helps! HUGE thanks!

Comment: The original was about automatically updating repodata to present the latest information (something apt-get doesn't do, or at least didn't in 2011). After the edit it's now kind of weirdly meaningless :(.

Comment: Why isn't it recommended to run `yum makecache`?  It's listed in the man page and seems to work like `apt-get update`... also note that `yum check-update` doesn't always perform a refresh, see other answers, FWIW :)

Comment: @rogerdpack I've never heard a recommendation against `yum makecache`.  I think that many people just say it's not worth running it; because, if the cache is old or expired, then yum updates the cache before any command that might modify the system.  So `yum makecache` will make the next commands faster; but, if you forget it, then `yum check-update` will update the cache too, before it checks for updates.

Comment: Because it will almost always do way more work than is required. There is a lot of logic in yum to keep the metadata updated automatically, without the user having to manually run a metadata sync command. Probably hundreds of lines of code since this question was asked. Even, `yum clean expire-cache` was probably added after this question was asked.

Answer (score 128):

The `check-update` command will refresh the package index and check for available updates:

```
yum check-update
```

Comment: This command allows you to determine whether any updates are available for your **installed packages**. `yum` returns a list of all package updates from all repositories if any are available. `apt-get update` refresh index files but `yum check-update` does not.

Comment: This doesn't work if `yum` has already been run recently, see some of the other answers for alternatives...

Comment: yum makecache is the right answer bcos check-update cannot be run until  a certain amount of time has expired - about 90 mins or more ...

Comment: This command does **not** refresh the package index.

Answer (score 43):

Unfortunately `yum check-update` by default doesn't pull down changes from remote repositories until `yum.conf`'s metadata_expire parameter has elapsed (default 90m).  Apparently its purpose is "know if your machine had any updates that needed to be applied without running it interactively" so basically it's "check if any packages are update-able" not "refresh the list of packages that I could update to" as you'd expect.

So if you run `yum check-update` and get this:

```
$ sudo yum check-update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

packagename      version     repo
```

This means that check-update is *not* performing an update, like `apt-get update` does.

You can see how long it will take before doing the "auto refresh" that all commands do underneath, by running [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350321/8337): `yum repolist enabled -v`

Work around:

[use](https://superuser.com/a/341228/39364) `yum clean expire-cache` (or `yum clean all`) first, then any future yum commands will auto-refresh the cache "when run."  . Because future yum commands refresh the cache, this is in practice the same as `apt-get update`.

Or change the metadata_expire parameter of yum.conf to less than the default 90min, I guess.

Or run `yum makecache` (from the other answers) which seems to remove the cache and pull down fresh copies right then.  But it seems to take longer than `clean xxx` FWIW (?)

Comment: Not sure why this answer is languishing at the bottom. This seems like the obvious and simple answer.

Answer (score 9):

That is the command to update the local cache, hence

```
yum makecache
```

seems to be the command you are looking for, according to [Working with Yum cache](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-working_with_yum_cache).

Normally you shouldn't need to run this command directly as yum already checks and refreshes metadata based on metadata_expire value in yum.conf, default being 6 hours.

However, there might be at least one use case, which is in an Ansible playbook, as you don't have a way in an Ansible playbook to only update the cache without installing any packages (See Ansible issues [33461](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/33461) and [40068](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/40068), which seems to be fixed in version 2.8, [46183](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/46183)). Ansible yum module requires a package name for 'update_cache: yes' option to have an effect. So, as an alternative 'command: yum makecache' can be used in the playbook.

dnf also has a makecache command, although it is also possible to force metadata synchronization with the --refresh switch.

Comment: [This existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7107/86440) already mentions `yum makecache`; perhaps you could expand your answer to make it more useful, for example by explaining why `yum makecache` isn’t recommended, or what the `dnf` equivalent is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Centos Stream 9, and the simple command to pulling and updating is:

`yum update`

The command pulls all app updates and installs it automatically and it also does checks for available OS updates and attempts to update it, but it stops at the point of attempting to install the OS & Kernel updates to request for a confirmation before continuing, hence, you only need to allow it do the OS installation by typing `Yes`.

Things appears to be easier with Centos9 Stream 9 in the terminal for Redhat CentOS.